# Compactness of closed bounded set implies least upper bound property?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

The least upper bound property of $\Bbb{R}$ implies the compactness of closed bounded subsets of $\Bbb{R}.$

I was wondering, does the converse hold? That is, does the property "closed bounded subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ are compact" imply the least upper bound property of $\Bbb{R}$?

I assume not because I never seen it (at least my analysis book never say a word about it). I know it's not an argument but I cannot find a counterexample.

Comment: The answer is, as you suspect, no.  There are general results that state something to the effect of "closed and bounded subsets of a metric space are compact" (you actually need slightly more hypotheses about the spaces, but these are not relevant to the current question, I think).  However, there are metric spaces that do not have the least upper bound property.  An easy example is $\mathbb{R}^2$.  In $\mathbb{R}^2$, closed and bounded sets are compact, but $\mathbb{R}^2$ does not have the least upper bound property.

Comment: @XanderHenderson As to $\mathbb{R}^2$ in what order do you use on it?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not ordered.  That's an additional hypothesis is required, no?  Though, to be fair, perhaps I should have assumed it, given the question.

Comment: @XanderHenderson For me, the context is linearly ordered topological spaces, as there we have a natural connection between order and topology, as in the reals.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Indeed, as acknowledged above, that probably the appropriate context in which to understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For linearly ordered topological spaces $X$ (LOTS) in the order topology, the following are equivalent:

- $X$ is compact.
- $\forall A \subseteq X$: $\sup A \in X$ exists. (where $\sup \emptyset = \min(X)$, by common convention)

Now suppose that $X$ is a LOTS such that every interval $[a,b],a < b \in X$ is compact.
Then $X$ has the lub-property: Let $A \subset X$ be a non-empty set that has an upperbound $B$. We want to see that $\sup A$ exists in $X$.
Pick any $a_0 \in A$ and by assumption $[a_0,B]$ is compact. Then $s=\sup(A \cap [a,B])$ exists in $[a,B]$ (note that as an order convex closed subset of a LOTS, the subspace topology and the topology from the restricted order topology coincide, so that $[a,B]$ is a compact LOTS and so has all sups). One easily checks that $s = \sup(A)$ as well.

So if we translate "closed and bounded" as a closed interval, yes, we do have a sort of converse..

Comment: Why does s exists?

Comment: @WilliamElliot $[a,B]$ is a compact LOTS; it has all sups, as I said at the start.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean as closed bounded interval?

Comment: @Byung yes $[a,B]$ is a closed interval.

Comment: @Byung all intervals are "bounded" in the order by their left and right endpoint.. And in any order topology a set like $[a,b]$ is closed.